# If the integer representation used is "0 through 4,294,967,295 (2^32 − 1)", so does this mean the register cannot handle negative numbers?

Tags: cpu, bit-manipulation

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit_computing#:%7E:text=With%20the%20two%20most%20common,for%20representation%20as%20two%27s%20complement.):

> A 32-bit register can store 2^32 different values. The range of integer values that can be stored in 32 bits depends on the integer representation used. With the two most common representations, the range is 0 through 4,294,967,295 (2^32 − 1) for representation as an (unsigned) binary number, and −2,147,483,648 (−2^31) through 2,147,483,647 (2^31 − 1) for representation as two's complement.

---

So if the integer representation used is "0 through 4,294,967,295 (2^32 − 1)", so does this mean the register cannot handle negative numbers?

---

From a similar standpoint, if the integer representation used is "−2,147,483,648 (−2^31) through 2,147,483,647 (2^31 − 1)", so does this mean that the register cannot handle numbers greater than 2,147,483,647?

Comment: I feel like we're going in circles. A 32-bit register is a collection of 32 bits. That's it. If you treat it as encoding an unsigned integer, it can store any integer from $0$ to $2^{32}-1$. If you treat it as encoding a signed integer using two's complement, it can store any integer from $-2^{31}$ to $2^{31}-1$. If you treat it as storing a fixed point unsigned with 2 bits after the dot, it can store any number from $0$ to $2^{30}-1/4$ in jumps of $1/4$. And so on.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus What's the highest and lowest value it can represent?

Comment: Whatever you want. It depends on the representation. In [IEEE 754 binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), the answer is $(2 − 2^{−23}) × 2^{127}$.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus Thanks, I will go through it.

Comment: @NirajRaut You need to realize the distinction between what can be represented and how many different things (assuming that different things should have different representations) can be represented. $2$ bits can represent $2^2=4$ different things. You can represent $5$. You can say that $00$ represents $5$, $01$ represents `dog`, $10$ represents `-0.12` and $11$ represents $\star$. We cannot represent the integers from $0$ to $5$ with $2$ bits because we would need to repeat a code.

Comment: @plop What does it mean by "...processors can work with 32-bit binary numbers"? To be more clear: what does it mean by a 32-bit processor? I know this has been answered but still, some confusion lingers.

Comment: @plop I mean we say that it can represent a decimal number up to 4,294,967,295, and after that, we say that it can also be greater than 4,294,967,295. That's why the confusion.

Comment: @NirajRaut: "I mean we say that it can represent a decimal number up to 4,294,967,295, and after that, we say that it can also be greater than 4,294,967,295" – No, *we* are not saying that. *You* are saying that. *We* are saying that a 32-bit register can represent 4,294,967,295 different *things*, and that's it. The register doesn't care what those "things" are. *You* define what those "things" are. You can define that they are the numbers 0 to 4,294,967,295, or you can define that they are the numbers 100,000,000,000 to 104,294,967,295, or you can define something else entirely.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag Hey, if we need to access memory more than what 32b addressing provides us, will the computer break the data, or will it stop the process?

Comment: Conceptually, a register does not “handle” anything, it just stores and regurgitates information; a 32-bit register stores 32 bits, giving 2³² combinations. A _processor_ handles the information and typically does things like retrieve bits from two registers, interpret them as two numbers in binary, form the binary representation of their sum [modulo 2³²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) and store it in another register. One usually adopts a convention that the possible combinations represent either 0–2³²-1 (“unsigned”) or -2³¹–2³1-1 (“signed”).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of a register don't have any inherent semantics.

Some instructions might assume certain semantics. For example, the x86 ADD instruction assumes that the registers represent integers, either unsigned or signed using two's complement. There are signed and unsigned versions in the x86 architecture for the multiplication instructions. Another unlikely place in which sign makes a difference is promotion instruction, in which a smaller register is assigned to a larger register – you want either zero extension (in the unsigned case) or sign extension (in the signed case, assuming two's complement).

What this all means is that certain the instruct set favors some interpretations by having instructions that assume them, but beyond that, the interpretation of the data stored in a register is completely up to the user. Moreover, in x86 at least, the same register can be used for both signed and unsigned operations. The register doesn't "know" which type of data it stores – it is completely up to the programmer. (One could imagine different architectures with different conventions.)